Pass data from node.js to .ejs js script variable
I must be overlooking something but I don't manage to get a variable from node.js to pass on into a js script object/variable in .ejs.
I have a route:
app.get('/simulation', (req, res) => {
  console.log("simulation results route requested");
  hotels = [
    {
      hotel: 'Hotel Tevini ****superior'
    }
  ];
  console.dir(priceTravelers, {depth:null});
  res.render('simulation/simulation', {jsonData: hotels});
});

And I want that data to be parsed in to a variable in the .ejs file.
I have tried
const data = <%= jsonData %>;

in the .ejs but that does not seem to work.
Any thoughts?
I tried several things like data = JSON.parse(<%= jsonData %>);.
Stringify the data on render to send first and then parse on the .ejs side but that gives [object][object] back etc.

"but that does not seem to work" - What does it do?  Is there an error?  An unexpected result?  Something else?

Try
const data = <%- JSON.stringify(jsonData) -%>;

jsonData is being sent to the EJS templater as an object, this is not the same as being seen in the resulting HTML file as an object.
If you have EJS turn the object into a string, then that resulting text will be understood by the browser.
Try this in the .ejs template:
const data = <%- JSON.stringify(jsonData) -%>;

This should result in the following HTML being sent to the browser:
const data = [{"hotel":"Hotel Tevini ****superior"}];


ah, that does the trick!!! Thank you very much, I've been scratching my head on this for hours...
